# how to generate hexadecimal number in range between 63 to 2048 using shell script

Tags: shell

echo $( NUMBER=0; FLOOR=63; RANGE=2048; \
                                                                                                                                     while [ $NUMBER -le $FLOOR ]; do \

NUMBER=$RANDOM; \

let "NUMBER %= $RANGE"; \

done; \

echo $NUMBER;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
randomintfromrange() { echo $(( ( RANDOM % ($2 - $1 +1 ) ) + $1 )); }
printf '%x\n' $(randomintfromrange 63 2048)
```

To repeat 100 times:

```
for ((;i++<100;)); do printf '%x\n' $(randomintfromrange 63 2048); done
```

Comment: addition: i want to generate random hex number

Comment: The code you posted does `-bash: printf: randomintfromrange: invalid number` on my system and prints `0` `3f` and `800` on separate lines. You are missing a `$( )` - `printf '%x\n' $(randomintfromrange 63 2048)`

Comment: Corrected missing `$( )`

Answer (score 1):

This bash function may help:

```sh
# usage: inrange num min max
# example: inrange 123456 63 2048  # => 387

inrange() {
    printf "%X" $(( $2 + $1 % ($3 - $2 + 1) ))
}
```

and then

```
for ((i=0; i<5000; i++)); do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" $i $(inrange $i 63 2048)
done
```

Comment: i want to generate random hex number in range between 63 to 2048

Comment: Ok. `inrange $RANDOM 63 2048`